# QNetworkAccessManager doesn't change ip address

Tags: qt, ftp, qnetworkaccessmanager

Consider this code snippet:

```
void MainWindow::sendToFTP()
{
    QMap<QString, QByteArray> _mapImgs;
    QByteArray arr("abcdefghjkl", 11);
    _mapImgs.insert("e.g.A", arr);
    QByteArray arr2("lkihgfedcba", 11);
    _mapImgs.insert("e.g.B", arr2);

    QNetworkAccessManager * _nam=new QNetworkAccessManager();
    QUrl _url;
    _url.setScheme("ftp");
    _url.setPort(21);

    // send e.g.A to 192.168.1.23
    _url.setHost("192.168.1.23");
    _url.setUserName("user");
    _url.setPassword("pass");
    _url.setPath("e.g.A");
    QNetworkReply * reply = _nam->put(QNetworkRequest(_url), _mapImgs["e.g.A"]);

    // send e.g.B to 192.168.1.24
    _url.setHost("192.168.1.24");
    _url.setUserName("user");
    _url.setPassword("pass");
    _url.setPath("e.g.B");
    QNetworkReply * reply2 = _nam->put(QNetworkRequest(_url), _mapImgs["e.g.B"]);

}
```

The test result is both A and B had been sent to 192.168.1.23, nothing is sent to 192.168.1.24.
But Why?

Comment: Is this code snippet is the real codeblock from your source? You are calling _nam->put some times just after each over? this will not work. Use several QNAM for such kind of calls.

Comment: @Xplatforms yes, it is almost real code. I use the same _nam instance to put content to different server. Why this code doesn't work? or how can I change _nam to another server?

Comment: Looks not like real code. If you do it this way, you can get problem with Qurl in QNR and then in QNAM because QNR takes reference of Qurl and you change this right after that. may cause problems on some platforms, may work on another, hangs on implementation. try to use different Qurl variables. But how do you check it calls only *.23 ip? what do you get in finished slot? What happens if you use different QNAM for this two calls? Does it work then? Just show us minimal runnable example of you problem.

Comment: @Mike, In addition you are not declaring QHostAddress, you are just passing a _string_ to `_url.setHost`, this is not good way of doing it.

Comment: This should just work, try printing to terminal the url.toString() to see how it looks like, but I write code like that and it just works, and yes using a single QNAM is fine.

Comment: @Xplatforms this code can run. I got both e.g.A and e.g.B at host *.23, nothing found at *.24. I didn't try different QNAM, because I don't need to send data to different host at the same time. I think just one QNAM is enough.